# WFFM enable custom field type for username in "Create User" save action

Tags: wffm

Is there some way to enable a custom WFFM field to be used for the username in the "Create User" save action? The dialog is shown here:
[image]

I've tried looking at the xaml file for this dialog (`\Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Modules\Web Forms for Marketers\Dialogs\Action Editor\CreateUser.xaml.xml`) and the associated code-behind (`Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.Dialogs.CreateUserPage, Sitecore.Forms.Core`) but cannot see any way to customise what field types are accepted. I noticed that the allowed types for a password are configurable via query parameter, but cannot see any reference to the `NameField` dropdown in the code-behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in a base class of `CreateUserPage`. This class inherits `AuditMembershipActionPage` which inherits `MemberhipActionPage`. `MemberhipActionPage` has a property called `UserNameAllowedTypes` which appears to read a query string parameter but defaults to a set list of field type IDs.

In order to supply the necessary query string parameter, I created a new save action as a copy of the OOTB "Create User" save action. The only thing I changed was to modify the "Editor" field to include query string parameters `?UserNameAllowedTypes=%7B88CECAB3-B76C-4E77-9255-DE5916334B8D%7D` where `88CECAB3-B76C-4E77-9255-DE5916334B8D` is the ID of my custom field type.

[image]